# How to hide [1] in print() in R

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When I use(in R)

```
print("<br><br>")
```

Output I get is

```
[1] <br><br>
```

instead is it possible to get just

```
<br><br>
```

I want to embedd the above in an HTML document.

Comment: Use `cat("<br/><br/>")` instead.

Comment: Great. I did not know about that function. Thanks.

Comment: @nrusse; the [1] is gettin rendered.

Comment: `br()` in shiny. or `HTML("<br><br>")`.

Comment: To terminate with a newline, use `fill=TRUE`, or use the `message` function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Backlin mentioned, `cat` will hide the `[1]`.

Another useful function to have lying around (at least if you come from a C-family background) is

```
printf <- function (...) {
    invisible(cat(sprintf(...)))
}
```

See `?sprintf` for details.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `message()`. Example (R interpreter):

```
> message('<br><br>')
<br><br>
```